# How use fastJSON with a JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, fastjson

I am using [fastJSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON) to read data from a JSON file that I made, (the JSON file have data of a game's levels for a project in Unity, but that is not important). This is the JSON content:

```
{"1": {
    "background": "background1.png",
    "description": "A description of this level",
    "enemies": 
              [{"name": "enemy1", "number": "5"},
               {"name": "enemy2", "number": "2"}]},
 "2": {
    "background": "background1.png",
    "description": "A description of this level",
    "enemies": 
              [{"name": "enemy1", "number": "8"},
               {"name": "enemy2", "number": "3"}]},
"3": {
    "background": "background2.png",
    "description": "A description of this level",
    "enemies": 
              [{"name": "enemy2", "number": "5"},
               {"name": "enemy3", "number": "3"},
               {"name": "enemy4", "number": "1"}]}
}
```

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using fastJSON;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private Dictionary<string, object> currentLevelData;

    public TextAsset levelJSON;
    public int currentLevel;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        currentLevelData = LevelElements (currentLevel);
        if (currentLevelData != null) {
            Debug.Log (currentLevelData["background"]);
            Debug.Log (currentLevelData["description"]);
            /* How iterate the "enemies" array */
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Could not find level '" + currentLevel + "' data");
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, object> LevelElements (int level) {
        string jsonText = levelJSON.ToString();
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = fastJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonText) as Dictionary<string, object>;

        Dictionary<string, object> levelData = null;
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey (level.ToString ())) {
            levelData = dictionary [level.ToString ()] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        }

        return levelData;
    }
}
```

I don't know how iterate the array data with the name "enemies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way your code is currently written, you would iterate over the enemies like this:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> enemy in (List<object>)currentLevelData["enemies"])
{
    Debug.Log(enemy["name"]);
    Debug.Log(enemy["number"]);
}
```

However, I would recommend making some strongly typed classes to receive your data:

```
public class Level
{
    public string background { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Enemy> enemies { get; set; }
}

public class Enemy
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally, this would allow you to deserialize like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Level> dictionary = 
                          fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<Dictionary<string, Level>>(jsonText);
```

Unfortunately, it seems that fastJSON cannot handle this (I tried it and got an exception).  However, if you switch to a more robust library like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), it works with no problem:

```
Dictionary<string, Level> dictionary = 
                        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Level>>(jsonText);
```

This would allow you to rewrite your code so you can work with your data more more easily:

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Level currentLevelData;

    public string levelJSON;
    public int currentLevel;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        currentLevelData = LevelElements(currentLevel);
        if (currentLevelData != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(currentLevelData.background);
            Debug.Log(currentLevelData.description);

            foreach (Enemy enemy in currentLevelData.enemies)
            {
                Debug.Log(enemy.name);
                Debug.Log(enemy.number);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not find level '" + currentLevel + "' data");
        }
    }

    Level LevelElements(int level)
    {
        string jsonText = levelJSON.ToString();
        Dictionary<string, Level> dictionary = 
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Level>>(jsonText);

        Level levelData = null;
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(level.ToString()))
        {
            levelData = dictionary[level.ToString()];
        }

        return levelData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You really helped me not only to solve my question, but also to understand how works  this frameworks to serialize objects.
Voted best answer and up voted!